# I deleted sudo on purpose and terminal is asking me for sudo passwd

Tags: chromebook

I was getting a lot of errors that I didn't know how to fix everytime I typed "sudo apt-get update" I was kinda new and didn't know who to fix it after countless hours of research so I decided to remove sudo. Now everytime I try to install sudo back I get prompted with the following:

```
   We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local system Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

        #1)Respect the privacy of others.

        #2)Think before you type.

        #3)With great power comes great responsibility.

   [Sudo] password for "my user name is here"
```

I don't know my sudo password and I now know I should never have deleted it. Is there a way I can reset everything so I can have a new terminal that ask me for a user name and password. I'm using linux(beta) on chrome os.

Thanks a lot if you are able to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your sudo password is your normal login password. If for some reason you aren't admin, become root([this may help](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001639.htm)) and then change permissions (and passwords if necessary. In the end, all you need to be is root, and that by itself can and reset the sudo password.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but did you mean my sudo password is the password I use to login my chromebook. If so I tried that and it didn't work. I tried to login as root by using "su" in the command line, but once again was asked for a password in which I dont know. The alternative way to login to root is to use sudo which I dont have. I'm mostly trying to find a way to just reset everything. I know uninstalling lunix wont help that, but when I first got terminal from linux, the sudo command was already there. Thanks if you can help with this